# place background image on nav bar and allow over flow into next section

Tags: css, html, image, navbar

I would like to place a background image i made behind my nav bar that is responsive to the viewport (gets smaller when the window gets smaller). The image looks like this:

[Nav Bar Background Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7eaQW.png)

I would like the black band to be behind the nav bar and for the arm to then go into the next section. I would like the text of the next p to not over lap the arm and to align around it.

Is it possible to do this using CSS? Using HTML5.

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the black bar behind the navigation is just a rectangle, you can use CSS to set a `background-color` of `#000` on a div for your navigation bar, have it be 100% width, and set a height on it. Then, simply put your navigation text/buttons inside of that `div`.

From there, you can have just the arm be a background image for the next element in your HTML, and use `background-position: top right` to align it to the right side of the page and top so that it touches the black navigation bar.

Hope that helps! Let me know if you need more help and I can do something in a codepen real quick :D

Comment: Thank you so much! The black bar works a treat and the background image work a treat, however there is a gap between the 2 bars due to padding-top on my next html element which i need to stop the title touching the navbar. Is there a way i can exclude the goldenarm background img from the padding? Thanks again

Comment: Sure, instead of having the padding-top on the next html element, simply add another element _inside_ of the next htm element and put your padding there.